# get certain set of object using the specified value php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Good day! I have a question with regard to retrieving specific object from Array in Object(Php Laravel).
Say for example

This is where the data that I want to retrieve :

```
$variable = [array];
// This is the result whenever I use this on blade to see the result of the variable. 
json_encode($variable, true); 

//result 
   [
     {"0":{
           "id":1,
           "name":"Joe",
           "year":2012,
          },
     }, 
     {"0": 
          {
           "id":2,
           "name":"Mark",
           "year" : 2020,
          }
     }, 
     {"0": 
          {
           "id":2,
           "name":"Mark",
           "year" : 2020,
          }
     }

   ]
```

I want to use php to retrieve item that has year = 2020 and id = 2 and insert it inside the new variable.

so I am expecting that the result will be :

```
  [ 
    { 
     "0": 
          {
           "id":2,
           "name":"Mark",
           "year" : 2020,
          } 
    },
   {"0": 
          {
           "id":2,
           "name":"Mark",
           "year" : 2020,
          }
     }
   ]
```

I have tried :

```
  $new_val = []
  foreach($variable as $key => value) {
     if($value['year'] == "2020" && $value['id'] == "2") {
         array_push($new_val , $variable[$key]):
     }
  }
```

Thank you for reading my question

Comment: What have you tried? In the simplest form, you could just loop over your input array, check if year and id of the current item match those values you are looking for, and if so, you simply add the current item to your output array …

Comment: +1 to the "what have you tried" question. Once we see how far you've gotten, we might be able to help you identify any flaws in the logic or code.

Comment: Hi, I have provided my code snippet of what I have tried. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`````
$variable[] = [
    "id"   => 1,
    "name" => "Joe",
    "year" => 2012,
];
$variable[] = [
    "id"   => 2,
    "name" => "Mark",
    "year" => 2020,
];

function _search($array, $name, $year)
{
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if ($item['name'] == $name && $item['year'] == $year) {
            return $item;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
$new = _search($variable, 'Mark', '2020');
print_r($new);````
`````

Comment: this resulting me an error : Undefined index: year, maybe because of the structure of the array I have provided is not match on your array example.

Comment: and it returns 1 item only

Comment: this somehow solved the problem that I have. Thanks :D

Comment: Hello Cleiton! It looks like you have a pretty solid answer here, but it is often helpful to include some context as to how your answer solves the problem, instead of just a code snippet. Otherwise, it looks like you are already helping someone. Welcome to the site!